# Adding and Saving Role Selector to WooCommerce "My Account" to Allow New Users To Choose Between "Customer" and "Vendor"

Tags: woocommerce, registration, account

I have been trying various ways to accomplish this, but no matter what I do, the screen either turns white or I get "Fatal error" (`wp-die`) kind of thing.

The general idea is to let the user choose between being a "`Customer`" as in "Can only buy" and "`Vendor`" which is "Can add products, but not publish them".

But, first things things first. This is the code that crashes everything for me:

```
// Add a user role field to the registration form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_vendor_role_to_registration' );
function add_vendor_role_to_registration( $form ) {

    $form[ 'account' ] [ 'account-role' ] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => 'Choose Your Account Type',
        'options' => array(
            'customer' => 'Customer',
            'vendor' => 'Vendor',
        ),
        'required' => true,
    );
    return $form;
}

// manage role after registration
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'set_user_role_based_on_registration' );
function set_user_role_based_on_registration( $customer_id )
{
    if ( isset ( $_POST[ 'account-role' ] ) && in_array( $_POST[ 'account-role' ], array( 'customer', 'vendor' ) ) ) {
        $role = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'account-role' ] );

        // remove existing roles
        $user = new WP_User( $customer_id );
        $user->set_role('');

        // set the user role based on selection
        $user->add_role( $role );
    }
}
```

Comment: use wp_update_user() instead of seting or adding roles - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/ where $userdata is array something like wp_update_user(array('ID' => $customer_id, 'role' => $role)); should be fine ?

Comment: Tried that, no success. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: and what errors you get ?

Comment: My apologies for not providing that. The same thing: `"Fatal Error"` or just a `wp_die();` screen. It weird since there's no other code or plugins active.

I just, for future reference, need to the person registering to have the option between two roles. Rules will be applied to those roles later, but as of right now - it just "crashes".

Comment: If you were able to use your own solution and that way, make it work - please post that code so that I can test it.